# (How) does a cmake configuration differ conceptually from a Visual-C++ project file?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, projects-and-solutions

To get from C++ sourcecode to a binary module, the process is roughly as follows:

```
set_of_source_files[a.cpp, b.cpp, ...] // conceptually, it doesn't matter where these are

          ||
          || Compiler  <- [compiler_settings]
          \/

set_of_object_files

          ||
          || Linker  <- [linker_settings]
          \/

binary module (dynamic library or executable)
```

Now, *I know* Visual Studio projects, they

- Define a set of source files (directory structure and layout basically doesn't matter / is defined inside the project file)
- Define the compiler settings for all (optionally each) of the source files
- Define the linker settings
- Define where to put generated output files

I *don't know* [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/), but apparently(**?**), the info one configures with cmake differs slightly from the info one puts into `vc[x]proj` files.

**Is a "cmake configuration" just a differently formatted "vcproj file" or is there a conceptual difference?** (Except for the obvious one (I assume) that the info I put into a cmake configuration is platform independent.)

An alternative twist to this question would be to answer -- in the context of above -- why/if(?) one would switch to cmake when *only* compiling for Windows with Visual-C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmake is a cross-platform make -- it starts from a set of source files and a relatively abstract set of directions about what to do with them. Based on those, it generates a set of platform-specific files. If you specify Windows/Visual Studio as the target, it can/will generate a vx[x]proj file for you to use.

Even if you're only using Visual C++ on Windows, it's *possible* you could benefit from cmake. The obvious possibility would be if you want to target a number of different versions of Visual Studio, and be able to directly generate the correct files for each, instead of generating files for the oldest version you want to support, and then depend on Visual Studio's upgrade feature to convert those to the target version.

Based on my experience with VS's upgrade capability (not particularly great), I'd say that could/would be a reasonable and valid use.

Comment: Is the way cmake "starts from a set of source files" *conceptually* very different from how you define a set of source files for a vcproj? Does the "abstract set of directions" have a different purpose than what you set for compiler and linker options in VC++?

Comment: @Martin: On a purely conceptual level, no, the ideas aren't drastically different. On a practical level, however, they're not even close to the same. Cmake produces output that's ready for your environment and compiler to work with. Your environment and compiler then produce output that's ready to run.